# pop up form not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to make form pop up . when the user clicks on contact me button  it will show the pop up form i was trying this code i know some of the syntax is wrong please help !

MY HTML

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
            <article>
                <h1>First Article</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </article>

            <form id="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

MY JQUERY

```
 (function(){

        var object = {

            formToShow:$('#form'),

            showForm: function(){
                $(this).object.formToShow.show();
            }

        };

        $('<button class="btn btn-default">Contact Me</button>').insertAfter('article:first').on('click', object.showForm);

    })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `$(this).object` is undefined, which causes a script error in the click handler.

`this` inside the handler refers to the dom element, and the jQuery object `$(this)` does not have a property called `object`.

One possible solution is to use a custom context for the callback method so that `this` inside the `showForm` when invoked will refer to the `object` instance.

```
$('<button class="btn btn-default">Contact Me</button>').insertAfter('article:first').on('click', object.showForm.bind(object));
```

---

Another solution could be is to access the closure variable `object` directly like

```
(function () {

    var object = {

        formToShow: $('#form'),

        showForm: function () {
            object.formToShow.show();
        }

    };

    $('<button class="btn btn-default">Contact Me</button>').insertAfter('article:first').on('click', object.showForm);

})();
```

Comment: @danialpervaiz if you add another function what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.Check snippet

```js
(function () {

    var object = {

        formToShow: $('#form'),

        showForm: function () {
            object.formToShow.show();
        }

    };
   //update button source
    $('<button class="btn btn-default">Contact Me</button>').insertAfter('article:first').on('click', object.showForm);

  
  
})();
```

```css
**Add css for form display**
#form{
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
**HTML code : nothing change in it**
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <article>
                <h1>First Article</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </article>

            <form id="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Comment: i have update jquery code for button and add css for form display none @Barmar

Comment: Put it in the answer. Explain specifically what the OP did wrong, and how you fixed it.